# X and Y in Bitmap and Open GL with Java

Tags: java, opengl

I've a problem with LWJGL and texture a quad with an char of a bitmap.
I want to display an uppercase *T*. The T is on the 6th row and the 5th colum. This is X: 40, Y: 32px from the upper left corner.

[image]

I use the following code:

```
GL11.glTexCoord2f((float) (Math.floor(charID / this.charsInRow) * charSize) / bitmapSize, (float) (Math.floor(charID % this.charsInRow) * charSize) / bitmapSize);
GL11.glVertex2f((charPosition * fontSize) + x, y);
GL11.glTexCoord2f((float) (Math.floor(charID / this.charsInRow) * charSize + charSize) / bitmapSize, (float) (Math.floor(charID % this.charsInRow) * charSize) / bitmapSize);
GL11.glVertex2f((charPosition * fontSize) + x + fontSize, y);
GL11.glTexCoord2f((float) (Math.floor(charID / this.charsInRow) * charSize + charSize) / bitmapSize, (float) (Math.floor(charID % this.charsInRow) * charSize + charSize) / bitmapSize);
GL11.glVertex2f((charPosition * fontSize) + x + fontSize, y + fontSize);
GL11.glTexCoord2f((float) (Math.floor(charID / this.charsInRow) * charSize) / bitmapSize, (float) (Math.floor(charID % this.charsInRow) * charSize + charSize) / bitmapSize);
GL11.glVertex2f((charPosition * fontSize) + x
                            ,y + fontSize);
```

But LWJGL count from the lower right corner sothat a strange ASCII symbol will be displayed.

What can I do so that the T will be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL normalized texture coordinates start from the lower-left corner (0,0) and go to the upper-right (1,1). In your question, you are using the wrong approach to address your glyphys - in particular, you should be starting from the bottom instead of top.

Judging by your example image, your coordinates should probably follow this format:

```
Glyph Bottom Left: (X - <GlyphWidth>, <TextureResY> - Y - <GlyphHeight>)
Glyph Top Right:   (X,                <TextureResY> - Y                )
```

*Where X and Y are 40 and 32 respectively.*

Also, you appear to have transposed your rows and columns.